# Anaconda uses Jupyter notebooks so why option to install VS Code?

Tags: python, anaconda, jupyter-notebook

I installed Anaconda as it's a recommended way to start with Jupyter notebooks.

I was surprised at the end of the Anaconda windows install to be invited to install Microsoft VS Code as a code editor. Reading about VS Code it seems a well respected editor but does that not take away the idea of using using Jupyter notebooks? Or am I missing something?

Comment: Even if you intend to mainly use notebooks, it should not mean you have to use them for everything. I typically take code that is greatly reusable and factor it into packages. That work is in my opinion better suited for an editor or IDE. That being said, the reason they suggest installing vs code is obviously due to financial incentives from Microsoft. Here's some details about the partnership https://www.datanami.com/2018/02/15/microsoft-anaconda-expand-python-partnership/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jupyter might recommend using Anaconda, but this doesn't imply that Anaconda would recommend using Jupyter.

You are right that if you are going to focus on Jupyter notebooks you won't need to use VS Code.

But most people that use Anaconda are not using Jupyter notebooks - they write python scripts not notebooks - and for that vscode is a respected choice.

Answer (score 2):

Anaconda also installs IDLE and Spyder, which are IDEs (Integrated Development Environments). Anaconda simply gives you a choice. Each of those choices has its advantages and disadvantages. Using one does not prohibit you from also using another.